# C# custom control task list

Tags: c#, visual-studio, properties, controls

I have been trying to find documentation on this for hours, but I cannot. How can I make certain properties of a custom control visible in the task list (like picture box or toolstrip)

I cannot upload images but, for example, if you create a picture box or a toolstrip on a form, there is the little black arrow on the top right that you can expand to find a task list.

I can view them in the properties window using [Category] and [Description] but I do not know how to view specific properties in the task window.

Thanks

Comment: ou mean visual studio?

Comment: Yes, I am doing this in visual studio 2013